# Why do my images get smaller when I give them a margin-left or float them left?

Tags: html, css, image, margin

This is the css for my social media bar. It's supposed to be on the right side of my page. When I use margin or float the images get really small.

```css
.facebook {
  width: 72.8%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: -9%;
  margin-top: 14%;
}

.insta,
.twitter {
  width: 49.2%;
  height: auto;
}

.social {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png" class="facebook" alt="Facebook Logo"></a>
</div> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<div class="social">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/-van-nederland-elgie-gaat-haar-ontwikkeling-posten-op-twitter-24.png" class="twitter" alt="Twitter Logo"></a>
</div> <br> <br> <br>
<div class="social">
  <a href="#"><img src="https://midflokkurinn.is/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/250ig.png" class="insta" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in this part of the code, should be in some other code you have on your site.

Comment: I put in my html as well. Is there a problem there?

Comment: The HTML is either in white font, I'm blind or you forgot to add it ;)

Comment: Sorry. You should be able to see it now

Answer (score 1):

The parent div has a standard with and height, if you give the child margins, it makes the space that it has smaller and smaller.

For example if you give something a height of 50px and a margin of 30xp its left with (50px - 30px) = 20px space to fill itself in.

U should give the images a height, for example

```
.facebook, .insta, ,twitter { 
   height: 50px;
   width: 50px;
}
```

and then you can give it whatever margin you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap these in a container and set the positioning on that. Spacing the icons to the right with 95% left margin just isn't going to give you nice results. Set your a tags to display block and give your images consistent dimensions and you'll be set. Finally, using br tags is not good practice for spacing. It will give you nightmares if you ever need to adjust that spacing, say on mobile views for example. You'll want to use padding or margins instead. Here is an example:

```css
#social-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 20px;
}

.social {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.social:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.social a {
  display: block;
}

.social img {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="social-container">
  <div class="social">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://facebookbrand.com/wp-content/themes/fb-branding/prj-fb-branding/assets/images/fb-art.png" class="facebook" alt="Facebook Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/-van-nederland-elgie-gaat-haar-ontwikkeling-posten-op-twitter-24.png" class="twitter" alt="Twitter Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="social">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://midflokkurinn.is/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/250ig.png" class="insta" alt="Instagram Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```